# MySQL Aggregate statistic with subquery in the table list

Tags: mysql, subquery, aggregate

I am working on an example query in sakila where I want to show the customer with the max count of rentals. Lots of ways to do this, both simpler and preferable, but I wanted to use a subquery in the table list. I got here and celebrated, until I quickly realized the rookie mistake: I get the max count, but just the first row from the left table.

```
SELECT customer.customer_id, first_name, last_name, max(Num_rentals) 
FROM customer
JOIN   
    (SELECT rental.customer_id, count(*) AS num_rentals
    FROM rental
    GROUP BY rental.customer_id) as Sub
ON customer.customer_id = sub.customer_id
;
```

I have tried a number of iterations to try to get at answer I want, and I would like something a bit more elegant than sorting the subquery and limiting the result there to a single row. BTW the correct answer is Elenor Hunt with 46. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show with sample data, what you are after.  It is not clear at all.

Comment: This is the sakila sample database... Looking for the customer with highest count of rentals.

Comment: Did you want to me to google it and download, just for you?  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I am sorry Rohit, but if you copy/paste my code using the sakila database, it is quite reproducible. It just doesn't yield the result I am looking for. If you can google it and find exactly what I am looking for I would welcome that. It is possible that what I am trying to do can't be accomplished the way I am trying to do it, and that is fine. If you don't have sakila, it is one of the sample databases that ships with MySQL although you may have to google that to install it.

Comment: That message is a standard one that fits the best, from the review queues.  Its not present on my mysql.  And you cant really expect people to google and to install something.  The reproducible bit refers to what you have posted.  One way id to load it on a fiddle.  Such as [1](https://dbfiddle.uk/) [2](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) [3](http://sqlfiddle.com/)  And then post a link to it.  It is also not clear what you want.  Post a sample output.